# getXpathCount that doesn't contain a zero

Tags: xml, xpath, selenium, phpunit

This is the code I have for Selenium/PHPUnit:

```
$this->getXpathCount("//img[contains(@src, 'yes_star')]/../div[contains(text(), '0')]
```

How can I rewrite this code to count the xpath for the elements that doesn't contain the text 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `not()` function, e.g.:

```
//img[contains(@src, 'yes_star')]/../div[not(contains(text(), '0'))]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Is there anywhere I can learn more about xpaths and its functions?

Comment: I was looking for some XPath tutorials, and it brought me to w3schools, but that one doesn't have too much information. The site you provided me seems like it has a lot of info. I'll take a look at it when I have time. Thanks!

Comment: @RaymondYan, It is original specification of XPath language, so it contains complete language description. You're welcome.